# Add CC in reply sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-ruby

I am sending an email from my desktop application using sendgrid. I can add cc when I am sending email.

But when user clicks on reply it will only send email to 'To' address automatically.
CC & BCC are empty in reply field.

I can set reply_to field with different email. But what I want to fill is 'CC' field.

How can I automatically fill 'CC' when user clicks on 'Reply' button using sendgrid

Regards

Ajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

In an email client, it is normal behaviour for there to be two buttons for replying to an email, *reply* and *reply all*. When a user clicks *reply*, the *To* email address will be filled in with the original email's *From* address or *Reply-To* address if it is present. When a user clicks *reply all* then the *To* email address and any other *CC* email addresses will be filled in.

However, you cannot control the behaviour of your users or their email clients from the SendGrid API. So you cannot make a user *reply all*.

Comment: so we can use reply_to for reply button. And reply all will do it's job by default.

Comment: Reply-to isn't going to add addresses to the `CC` field. But try some things out and see what works for you.